# Django unions and temporary fields in serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DjangoRest view that finds several QuerySets of a Model (Item), calculates a "rank" for each item, and then passes the final list to a serializer.

My "rank" field is a temporary field added by the serializer.

When I try something like the this:

```py
q_a = Item.objects.filter(some filter)
q_b = Item.objects.filter(some other filter)
q_c = Item.objects.filter(some other filter)

for item in q_a:
    item['rank'] = 5 #fixed rank
for item in q_b:
    item['rank'] = calulcateRank(type_b) #my function 
for item in q_c:
    item['rank'] = calculateRank(type_c) #my function  

final_q = q_a | q_b | q_c

serializer = ItemSertializer(final_q, many=True)
```

My rank field is lost by the serializer.

However, if I do this:

```py
q_a = Item.objects.filter(some filter)
q_b = Item.objects.filter(some other filter)
q_c = Item.objects.filter(some other filter)

final_q = q_a | q_b | q_c

for item in final_q:
    item['rank'] = calulcateRank() # with type logic inside now

serializer = ItemSertializer(final_q, many=True)
```

It works fine.

The second version is cleaner code and probably superior but I don't really understand what the issue is and would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queryset methods often returns a new queryset instances ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)). This means that cache is not preserved.

In your first example, iterating over your three querysets provoke SQL requests to occur and cache to be filled. You're then adding a field on the Python instances of your model in the queryset cache.
After the union, `final_q` is a new queryset that has yet to execute its SQL request. When the serializer will iterate over the queryset, it will get fresh new python instances of your model

PS: depending on the rank computation, you should probably do it with SQL

```
Item.objects.annotate(rank=Case(When(filter_a, then=Value(5)), When(filter_b, then=F(some_field) * 2), When(filter_c, then=F(some_other_field) / F(some_third_field)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise the cache was lost when the query was triggered. I need to look up some dynamic/user set ranking tables in the calulcateRank method so not sure I can turn it into an explicit query. Should I be trying to minimise union operations and replace them with more complex filters?

Comment: Performing operation in Python over a large queryset is rarely a good idea.  
If those data are served through a paginated API it might be faster to compute this value inside the serializer.  
Union is a powerful tool but is almost always the last operation on your queryset which can made it difficult for future evolutions.